# Calulated month from "Start Time", does it work in Your Online?

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calendar, start-time

Trying to get the text value of the month. Created a calculated column with a return type of 'Date', but can get the result only for 'Created' field.

**This works:**

```
=TEXT((MONTH(Created)),"MMMM")
```

Result, successfully:

[image]

But this not:

```
=TEXT((MONTH([EventDate])),"MMMM")
=TEXT((MONTH([Start Time])),"MMMM")
=TEXT((MONTH(['Start Time'])),"MMMM")
=TEXT((MONTH('Start Time')),"MMMM")
=MONTH(([EventDate]),"MMMM")
```

How?..

---

**update:** Thank You for the response, Mohammed!

Strange that You have more columns in Your multiple lookup("Insert column" on right side). I don't have 'Start/End Date' columns there:

[image]

[image]

Maybe some feature needed..

[image]

I have publishing enabled on this site-collection.

Comment: You are welcome @Gennady, Are you sure you have created the start date column, could you share the columns list in list setting page

Comment: My fail Mohamed! Your formula works. Thank You much! Friday..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try the below formula**

```
=TEXT([Start Date],"MMMM")
```

**Column Settings**

[image]

**[Output]**

[image]

> **Note** If the `Start Date` is not already created in the list or it's **Content-Type Columns**, so it will not be listed in the columns list in the Calculated column setting because
>   it's unsupported in the SharePoint 2010 / 2013 / 2016 calculated
>   column.
>
> For more details, check [The supported and unsupported columns in
>   SharePoint calculated column formula](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)